# more than a third is/are exported

Tags: singular-vs-plural

In the following sentence, should "are" or "is" be used?

> The country produces about one million tons of oil a year. More than a third are/is exported to Europe.

The issue is about whether "X tons," where X stands for a number, is singular or plural.

Answer (score 0):

"is" should be used in the sentence, because the "are" does not match with the subject.

A singular subject requires a singular verb, and a plural subject requires a plural verb. When there is a lot of text between the subject and the verb, it’s easy to lose track of which words need to agree.

When you need to determine what the subject is, it’s often helpful to ask who or what is “doing” the action of the verb.

In the sentence `There is a pie on the table` the word `there` can stand in as a grammatical subject.  In this type of construction, the verb is controlled not by the word there but by the logical subject of the clause, which usually comes right after the verb.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to the ELL. Your answer could be improved by providing references. See [tour](https://ell.stackexchange.com/tour).